# How to remove "X-Runtime" header from Nginx/Passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, http-headers, nginx, passenger

**EDIT** -- the solution I posted below probably applies to any server (Nginx/Apache/anything else), because this header is set in Rails itself.

---

Anyone know where the "X-Runtime" header can be removed in Nginx & Passenger?

I've grepped the source files and haven't found anything yet, but I'd like to get rid of it for security since it's a telltale sign of Rails.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the X-Runtime is not set by nginx. I suggest you check the Passenger sources.

Comment: I grepped both sources before asking the question but didn't see anything in either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turned out it wasn't being set in either Nginx or Passenger.

It's in benchmarking.rb in /gems/actionpack-2.3.2/lib/action_controller/, line 90.

Answer (score 10):

For anyone who is still stumbling on this, I believe the simplest and most correct way to do it is in config/application.rb, by adding the following:

```
config.middleware.delete(Rack::Runtime)
```

All the other methods seem to not so much disable the header as filter it from the output. This is for rails4, not sure if it applies to other versions.

**Update:**

The following code in an initializer file may be more robust as the existence of Rack::Runtime middleware might be assumed by some other components.

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.delete(Rack::Runtime)
```

Comment: This gave me this error: ```Exiting
/Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@wpvulndb/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:125:in `assert_index': No such middleware to insert before: "Rack::Runtime" (RuntimeError)``` in Rails 4.1.5

Comment: Perhaps there is some code trying to insert something before Rack::Runtime and assumes it is in the list of middleware. You can try this instead in an initializer file, which should sidestep the problem:

`Rails.application.config.middleware.delete(Rack::Runtime)`

Answer (score 4):

I know it's kinda old question but because problem still exists and many sites still expose it's passenger and nginx version I give answer which works very well for me. The same solution applies to X-Runtime header.

Just install 3rd party ngx_headers_more: http://github.com/agentzh/headers-more-nginx-module (you have to rebuild it from source). Add to your config (I created /etc/nginx/conf.d/security.conf for it):
server_tokens off;
more_clear_headers 'Server' 'X-Powered-By' 'X-Runtime';

Answer (score 2):

In Apache you can use [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_headers.html) to remove any header from the response (or the request for that matter).

To remove the headers you need to enable the module:

```
# a2enmod headers
```

Then you can use the unset option fo the Header directive to unset them:

```
Header unset X-Runtime
Header unset X-Powered-By
```

This directive can be used both at the global level and for the single virtual-server

Answer (score 1):

The following is for Apache. I didn't read the question correctly. :)

Enable the headers module, `mod_headers`, and add the following to Apache's configuration

```
Header always unset "X-Runtime"
```

You will probably also want to remove the `X-Powered-By` header so add the following too.

```
Header always unset "X-Powered-By"
```